# Java String Split to get individual data from a large string

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

I have the following data which is stored as a big string.

```
"John Chips Monday \n"

"Tom Pizza Tuesday\n"

"Jerry IceCream Wednesday\n"

"Jennifer Coffee Thursday\n"
```

Now I wish to split this string so I can get individual  data from this string and place each data in an array for example.

each element of names array stores the names seen above like names[0] = john, names[1] = Tom etc.
each element of food array stores the foods seen above like  food[0] = chips, food[1] = pizza.

I have tried doing this

```
    John + "\t" + Chips + "-" + Monday + "\n"

    Tom + "\t" + Pizza + "-" + Tuesday+ "\n"

    Jerry + "\t" + IceCream + "-" + Wednesday+ "\n"

    Jennifer + "\t" + Coffee + "-" + Thursday+ "\n"


    String nameCol[] = data.split("\\t");

    String foodCol[] = data.split("-");
```

The output I get is nearly there but wrong as it contains data that I don't want in the array for example the output for first array is

```
nameCol[0] = John

nameCol[1] = Chips -

nameCol[2] = Monday
```

Element 0 contains john but the other elements contain the parts I don't want.

I tried for a limit but this did not work

```
String nameCol[] = data.split("\\t",1);

String foodCol[] = data.split("-",1);
```

Comment: Can you say a bit more about how is the data stored/read? For me, it seems that you read this data from a file.

Comment: Read each line correctly and make sure that the respective words gets stored in the respective arrays(name array or food array)

Comment: Do you know how many lines are in the file?

Comment: First split on "\n" to get an array of rows. Then split each row on " " to get the individual column values for that row.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use them separately, use the *delimiters* together, like : [`String dataArr\[\] = data.split("\t\n",1);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
Then iterate through the `String[]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i+=2) {
    String name = dataArr[i];
    String food = dataArr[i+1];
    // ... do whatever you want with them.
}
```

---

Or, you could also try the similar [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)-[`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) approach

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
    String yourLine = "John Chips Monday\n"; // Read your line in here
    String[] resultCol = yourLine.split(" ");
    resultCol[2] = resultCol[2].split("\\n")[0];
    System.out.println( resultCol[2] );
```

The first split on the string will give you "John", "Chips" and "Monday\n". The second split takes "Monday\n" from the array and splits it. Returning "Monday" back into the final index of the array `resultCol[2]`. From here you can simply assign each element in the array to the arrays you require.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. use `List`s for each column, (Lists can increase their size dynamically, while arrays have fixed size)
2. iterate over each line,
3. split it on whitespace (or any separator you are using)
4. and add `column[0]` to list of names, `column[1]` to list of food and so on with other columns.

OR if you know that each line has only three words you could simply use Scanner and iterate over words instead of lines with split.

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    listOfNames.add(scanner.next());
    listOfFood.add(scanner.next());
    listOfDays.add(scanner.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your data, I assume that you are reading this values from a files. If you know how many lines there are, you could use 3 arrays, each for every type of data that needs to be retrived. If you don't know the size, you could go with 3 ArrayLists. Your problem is that after making the split, you didn't put them in the correct arrays. The following code assumes that you already have all the data in one String.

```
 final String values[] = data.split("\\n");
    final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String line : values) {
        String[] split = line.trim().split("[ ]+");
        names.add(split[0]);
        foods.add(split[1]);
        days.add(split[2]);
    }
```

Another thing that you must consider is to check if the data always has 3 values on a "line", or else further error checking is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     String str="John" + "\t" + "Chips" + "\t" + "Monday"  + "-" + "Test"+"\n"+"chet";

     String st1= str.replaceAll("(\\t)|(-)|(\n)"," ");

     String []st=st1.split(" ");

        for(String s : st)
        System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always going to be "[name] [food] [day]", then you could do:

```
String[] names = new String[allData.length]; //A list of names
String[] food = new String[allData.length]; //A list of food
String[] day = new String[allData.length]; //A list of days

for(int i = 0 ; i < allData.length ; i++)
{
    String[] contents = allData[i].split(" "); //Or use a similar delimiter.
    names[i] = contents[0];
    food[i] = contents[1];
    day[i] = contents[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    String s = "John Chips Monday \n Tom Pizza Tuesday \n Jerry IceCream Wednesday \n Jennifer Coffee Thursday \n";
    String split[] = s.split("\n");
    String names[] = new String[split.length];
    String foods[] = new String[split.length];
    String days[] = new String[split.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        String split1[] = split[i].trim().split(" ");
        names[i]=split1[0];
        foods[i]=split1[1];
        days[i]=split1[2];
        System.out.println("name=" + names[i] + ",food=" + foods[i] + ",day=" + days[i]);
    }
```